# Transfer events in MySQL to google calendar

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, google-calendar-api

I want to integrate my web app with google calendar, but I don't know if I can add to the calendar events. I have saved in my MySQL Database, I have searched but nothing seems to be answered.

I have a table with all the info google calendar needs, but I don't know how to integrate it and transfer those events to a google calendar

If i can't do this, what plugin of calendars can I use? Im working on PHP and using Twitter Bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a script/page that renders your pending events in [`iCal`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) format, then go to your Google Calendar, select [`Add by URL`](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100?hl=en) and provide the URL of the page you just created. Google will hit that page every so often to get updated events and display them as if they were local.

Comment: Thank you, if my URL is a local file, would it work? @Alex

Comment: Sure, you could write the iCal info to a local file and then just serve that file via your web server.

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding of Integrating Google Services try following links :
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_php

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google php client library[ https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ ]
to insert event using sample code spplied in following link 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

If you still have issues you can use this bootstrap calendar to create your own cal view
https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar